# How to find specific word in a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to know how to find a specific word in a text file without maybe using module `re`.
This is my current code:

```
searchfile = open("Menu.txt", "r")
myList = []
cho = input("What cusine would you like to view the menu for")


for line in searchfile:
    myList.append(line+"\n")

splitted_line = line.split(',')
print(splitted_line[0])
indian = (myList[0])
mexican = (myList[1])
italian = (myList[2])

if 'mexican' in cho:
    print(mexican)
elif 'indian' in cho:
    print(indian)
elif 'italian' in cho:
    print(italian)


searchfile.close()

cho2 = input("Would you like to order now or wait till later")
if cho2 == 'now':
    import practiseassessment.py

if cho2 == 'later':
    print("Ok for more information contact hungry horse at 07969214142")
```

This is the text file:

```
lamb curry , indian , chicken curry , indian vegtable curry , indian 
tacos , mexican fajitas , mexican nachos , mexican
margherita pizza , italian vegetable pizza , italian bbq chicken pizza , italian
```

I want to only print indian food when `cho == indian`.
I want the text file to be new line for every dish

Comment: Do you need to write the code on your own or are you allowed to use e.g. `csv` module or even `pandas`?

Comment: @albert write the code on my own

Comment: So using `csv` is not allowed? Handle the data as csv-formatted data would make the thing rather easy.

Comment: I just had a deeper look at you data. I think there are three commas missing. Could you please double check your data snippet? Where do you get your data from?

Comment: You forgot to strip out the white space after the split. And don't use re for this that's an overkill

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is one way to approach the problem. As you can see, you can do everything with python's builtin strings.

Note that use `str.lower().strip()` to normalize the search terms and the menu items before comparing them. That will give more generous results and not punish users for inputting extra spaces, and is usually a good thing.

```
# First parse you input file and create the menu list
with open("food.txt", "r") as foodfile:
    menu_items = ' '.join(foodfile.readlines()).strip().split(',')
menu_items = [item.strip() for item in menu_items]

# menu_items is now the list ['lamb curry', 'indian', 'chicken curry' ... etc

# I made the next part into a loop, so you can test several search terms.
# instead of searching on user input, you can split the menu into several lists
# but in most real world cases that is not really useful. With this approach
# users can search for "pizza" or "chicken" in addition to "mexican", "italian" etc. 

while True:
    cho = input("What cusine would you like to view the menu for? ").lower().strip()
    if not cho:  
        break  # break the loop if user submits an empty search string
    search_results = [food for food in menu_items if cho in food.lower()]
    print('\nFound %d items on the meny matching "%s"' % (len(search_results), cho))
    print(', '.join(search_results))

print('\ngoodbye')
```

example output:

> What cusine would you like to view the menu for? **indian**
>
> Found 3 items on the meny matching "indian" indian, indian vegtable
>   curry, indian tacos
>
> What cusine would you like to view the menu for? **mexican**
>
> Found 3 items on the meny matching "mexican" mexican fajitas, mexican
>   nachos, mexican margherita pizza
>
> What cusine would you like to view the menu for? **pizza**
>
> Found 3 items on the meny matching "pizza" mexican margherita pizza,
>   italian vegetable pizza, italian bbq chicken pizza

Comment: It works but the user should be able to type a sentence like this "i would like italian" of "can i buy some italian" so it should look for key words in the input @Haken Lid

Comment: You didn't mention that in the original question. Post a new question instead. I have very little experience with **natural language processing**, which is what you need to parse input like that. It's advanced stuff.

Answer (score -1):

First of all I had a deeper look at your data and I think you forgot some commas. So I assume the input data looks like this:

```
lamb curry , indian , chicken curry , indian , vegtable curry , indian
tacos , mexican fajitas , mexican nachos , mexican
margherita pizza , italian , vegetable pizza , italian , bbq chicken pizza , italian
```

There are several ways to get the desired output. However, I used `string` and `list` operations only in order to avoid using additional Python modules like `re`.
The only module I am using is `sys` module to abort the execution in order to exit the program if combining meal and origin would fail due to an uneven list length. However, you could get rid of this `sys.ext()` when writing dedicated functions by using an appropriate `return` statement. So this solution has the capability to work without additional modules. I think using `sys.exit()` is okay for the sake of demonstrating the idea.

For further explanation please see comments in code:

```
import sys

with open('data.txt', newline='') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

stripped_data = [line.replace(' , ', ',') for line in data]

# print in order to double check
print(stripped_data)

# write the whole data into a single string without newlines
s = ''
for line in data:
     s += line.replace(' , ', ',').replace('\n', ',')

# split string into several parts (which will be the meals and the origin)        
sliced = [e for e in s.split(',') if e]

# print in order to double check
print(sliced)

# exit routine if list has uneven length since we would fail when trying to combine the pairs
if len(sliced) % 2:
    sys.exit('Uneven list length. Would fail to combine pairs.')

# generate a list containing tuples of meal and origin --> (meal, origin)    
pairs = [(sliced[i], sliced[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(sliced), 2)]  

# ask the user what he wants to get served
wanted = input('What do you want to have? ')

# generate the output based on the user's input by accessing the tuples
output = [i for i,k in pairs if k == wanted]

# print the output
print(output)

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for meal in output:
        f.write('{}\n'.format(meal))
```

If the user wants `indian` meals the output file looks like this:

```
lamb curry
chicken curry
vegtable curry
```